# What is a "loop device" when mounting?

Tags: linux, grep, mount, loop-device

I am mounting an ISO file, and looking at [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html). They use the command:

```
$ mount -o loop disk1.iso /mnt/disk
```

I'm trying to understand the use of `-o loop`. I have two questions:

1. When I look at the long man page for mount, it takes time to find that `-o` option. If I do `man mount | grep "-o"` I get an error, and when I look in the file I do not find any info that "loop" is a command text for option `-o`. Where is that documented?
2. Also, what is the "loop device" concept for mounting?

Comment: In `man` you can search for a string by typing `/mystring` after man starts. You can highlight all matches with just `/`. See `man man`. I see @Josh has added such a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: For a related question I wrote [a short outline of the concept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66082/19575)

Comment: `/` is the standard search feature in vi, vim and almost all commands that output in pages (less, more...)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A loop device is a pseudo ("fake") device (actually just a file) that acts as a [block-based device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#BLOCKDEV). You want to mount a file `disk1.iso` that will act as an entire filesystem, so you use loop.

The `-o` is short for `--options`.

And the last thing, if you want to search for "-o" you need to escape the '-'.

Try:

```
man mount | grep "\-o"
```

Comment: With GNU grep, `grep -e -o` (`-e` says "next thing is the pattern no matter what it looks like) or `grep -- -o` (`--` means stop looking for switches) work too.  Of course feel free to use whatever works for you.

Comment: You can also just type: `man mount`, and then you can use `/-o` to search for and highlight all instances of "-o"

Comment: Although this makes sense, it seems that providing the `loop` option is not required.

Answer (score 46):

Traditionally, UNIX systems have had various types of nodes in their filesystems:

- directory
- file
- symlink
- block device
- character device
- FIFO
- UNIX domain socket

While there are now exceptions, generally block devices containing filesystems are mounted on directories.

Since you want to mount a file, you must first create a `loop` block device that is backed by the file.  This can be done using `losetup`, but `mount -o loop` is a shortcut that handles that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

Loop device is a device driver that allows you to mount a file that acts as a block device (a loop device is not actually a device type, it's an ordinary file).

For example:

```
mount -o loop demo.img /mnt/DEMO/
ls -l /mnt/DEMO/
```

You can now look at the `/mnt/DEMO` subdirectory for the contents of the demo.