# Cloning a bootable USB stick to a different-sized stick

Tags: live-usb, cloning, bootable

HARDWARE: 2 8GB USB flash drives
DISTRO: Mint 9 Xfce persistent Live Cd

One USB flash drive has two partitions:
1) FAT32 700MB Mint 9 partition
2) ext3 7.3GB `casper-rw` partition

GOAL:
I want to make a duplicate of that USB flash drive because I don't want to go through the time of installing and configuring from scratch again.

EXPERIENCE:
1) I have found that `dd` does not work for this job because if one of my flash drives is even 1MB different in size, which sometimes they are, then the copy gets corrupted.

2) I have found that using `gparted` and preformatting the second drive like the first and then `rsync`'ing each partition individually does not work because for some reason some files do not get copied and the drive remains unbootable.

I want to keep my working stick and just make copies of it and configure the sticks for my friends. This way if I goof up another stick I will always have my base stick just sitting around waiting.

Comment: what bootloader do you use (syslinux?). Please consider removing that rant from your post, it adds no value whatsoever to your question.

Comment: I used the mint live usb installer, so it was all automatic. I'm hoping the cloning process will avoid working with bootloaders and copy my current bootloader conf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Introduction

For a drive with PC partitions (which is what you'll find on most USB sticks), the bootloader consist in a tiny part at the very beginning of the drive (the stage 1 bootloader, in the boot sector of the drive) and a larger part elsewhere (the stage 2 bootloader, in a file). The stage 1 data contains the physical location of stage 2. If you copy the whole device (what you tried with `dd`), the stage 1 part is in the same physical location and the stick works, but the new stick has to be at least as large as the original. If you recreate the partitions and copy the files, you're missing the stage 1 since it's not a file.

I think (but I haven't checked) that the stage 2 is in the first (FAT32) partition. If so, you can copy that partition wholesale, and copy the boot sector as well, then edit the partition table so that the second partition occupies exactly the space that's left, and copy the files on the second partition. You might as well keep a raw image of the boot sector and of the first partition in a file on a hard disk (but you can clone them from a USB stick too).

#### Making a clone of a different size

Below I'll call the device containing the original stick `/dev/sdb` and the device containing the clone `/dev/sdc`; substitute names as needed. Create mount points if needed. I assume that the FAT32 partition (at the beginning of the disk) is numbered 1 and the ext3 partition is numbered 2; substitute different numbers if needed.

First part, if cloning from a stick:

```
head -c 512 </dev/sdb >/dev/sdc
partprobe /dev/sdc
cat </dev/sdb1 >/dev/sdc1
```

First part, if cloning from image files:

```
cat boot_sector.img >/dev/sdc
partprobe /dev/sdc
cat first_partition.img >/dev/sdc1
```

The call to `partprobe` is needed so that the kernel reloads the partition table from the disk (it's in the boot sector, and the first command in either scenario above modifies the boot sector). If you omit it, either you'll get errors or the kernel will silently write garbage to the stick.

To make the image files:

```
head -c 512 </dev/sdb >boot_sector.img 
cat /dev/sdb1 >first_partition.img
```

Now after you've got the boot sector and the first partition, you need to edit the partition table again, to resize the second partition. You can do this automatically by feeding the right input to `fdisk`. Warning, this is extremely error-prone, and I haven't tested it. If you don't feel completely comfortable with this part, do it by hand.

```
sed -e 's/ *#.*//' <<EOF | tr -s ' ' '\n' | tr -d _ | fdisk /dev/sdc
d 2         # delete partition 2
n p 2       # new primary partition 2...
_ _         # ... using all available space
w q         # write and quit
EOF
```

Finally reload the partition table again, create an ext3 filesystem, and copy the files there.

```
partprobe /dev/sdc
mke2fs -j /dev/sdc2
mount /dev/sdc2 /media/sdc2
cp -a /media/sdb2/ /media/sdc2/
umount /media/sdc2
```

#### Simplified method to make a larger clone

If you prefer, you can store an image of the whole stick. You'll be able to use that image directly on any stick that's at least as large: just copy that image onto the new stick with `cat <whole.img >/dev/sdc`, then run `partprobe /dev/sdc` (or unplug the stick and put it back in) to re-read the partition table.

Then, if you like, you can enlarge the clone. In this order:

1. Enlarge the partition. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in a simple way. `parted` can do it with the `move` command (not `resize`, which resizes the filesystem), but you need to figure out the right arguments — switch to sectors (`unit s`) to avoid rounding errors.
2. Enlarge the filesystem. That part is easy: just run `resize2fs /dev/sdc2` to make the filesystem use the whole partition size.

If you're starting from a larger stick than necessary, you can shrink it by following the steps above in the reverse order (first shrink the filesystem with `resize2fs`, then shrink the partition with `parted`).

Alternatively, you can first copy the stick to an image file, then work on that image file. To access the partitions, use a [loop device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/what-is-a-loop-device-when-mounting), specifically [associating a portion of the file to a disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/i-am-getting-an-error-trying-to-transfer-a-virtualbox-ose-vm-to-its-partition/9119#9119). Here's a sketch of the steps if you want to shrink the image (warning, untested, proceed carefully and double-check the math).

```
fdisk -lu whole.img  # note starting sector of partition 2: $S
losetup -fs -o $(($S * 512)) whole.img
# Let $D be the desired size of partition 2, in kB
resize2fs /dev/loop0 $  # replace /dev/loop0 by whatever losetup prints
losetup -d /dev/loop0
parted whole.img
# Use parted to resize the second partition
dd if=/dev/null of=/file/to/truncate seek=1 bs=$(($S/2+$D+1))k
```

Comment: hmm. Can't I just use head to just copy the first 300mb or so of the second partition into an img file? Won't that cut off all the empty space/ empty blocks at the end of the file?

Comment: @Joshua: No, because there's no reason why all the file data would be in the first 300MB, and even if it was you can't just take part of a filesystem like that. You need to make a valid filesystem of the right size. You also need to have a partition of the correct size; the size of the partition is stored in the boot sector. If you prefer to start from a minimum-sized image and enlarge it if desired, I've added a way to do that in my answer.

Comment: hmm. I tried copying the files before but for some reason everything didn't copy. I tried rsync too with sudo. and I think I tried su root and did it too .... It's just not working for me. I'm sure the drives were not mounted... anyways. I decided to shrink the drive in gparted and then make img files from that and then restore them onto a smaller disk. Pre-shrinking in gparted was the only simple solution I could find. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Your answer is probably correct and will most likely do what I am asking. It's just too complicated for me. So I went with gparted pre shrink method.

Comment: is there a typo in this line `head -c 512 </dev/sdb >/bev/sdc`?

Comment: Gilles, perhaps you might like to post an answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94801/44919

Answer (score 3):

> ~$: sudo apt-get install gddrescue ddrescue
>
> ~$: ddrescue /dev/sda /dev/sdb -v

;

Syntax: utility /source/drive /destination/drive --verbose

Comment: shows progress and error checking so you know if it is acceptable or hanging up somewhere.  You can also add **b=** whatever size blocks you want.  "gddrescue" is gui based version of "ddrescue" but I only use the ddrescue as written above since it works without a problem.

Comment: Note that proper format is `ddrescue -v /dev/sda /dev/sdb` (options come first before the names of the devices/files). Thanks for pointing out this tool! Much easier than using `dd`!

Answer (score 0):

I had recently cloned my Kali live encrypted persistence from a 16GB to a 64GB 3.0 USB, My host OS is windows 10 pro. I hadn't attempted to clone using any Linux distro, I'm sure the answers above are what you need, but for any windows users; I had used AOMEI disk partition assistant. Super simple to use, used it for partitioning my SSD to fit Ubuntu, but I digress.

I had to make sure that the USB I was cloning to had already been formatted for live booting. Plugged in both USB's and simply right clicked on the 8GB drive; clicked on `copy` then selected the 64GB drive, it'll ask you a bunch of things like "are you sure this is the right drive, everything will be erased" all that jazz. Just read through it and make sure everything is in order, you really don't have to do much.

Just wait for the process to be finished and you're all set. Tested said USB and everything worked!

I found this to be the easiest way at least for me, cloning live distros from USB to USB.